# Adding Custom Button to a Salesforce Standard Page

Tags: salesforce

How can a user that have Developer Account can add custom button to a standard page is there a way to do that. Because I couldn't find editing a button, adding a button or editing button's redirect URL for a standart visualforce edit page. i.e Opportunity creation form.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear :/

1. Your organisation is a "Developer Edition" (a free one to try out working on Force.com platform) or for example "Enterprise Edition" and your user Profile (a set of system permissions) is called "Developer"? In "Developer Edition" you probably are a System Administrator, so you have all the rights. In the later case - check if your profile has "Customize Application" permission for a start.
2. What do you mean by "standard visualforce edit page", there's no such thing. You mean standard page layout or do you have custom Visualforce Page that's used to edit opportunities?

---

Best guess answer:

You can go to Setup -> Customize -> Opportunities -> Buttons and Links, create there a "Detail Page Button" and when it's done - add it to the page layout(s) of Opportunities. If you don't see these options - you don't have permission to [customize application](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_enterprise.htm&siteLang=en_US).

BUT: none of the buttons added that way can be displayed on the "edit" page, which is a standard one with very limited customisation options. Only standard "view" page displays the extra buttons. There are some JavaScript tricks to inject content to "new/edit" (via section headers or sidebar)... But if you want the button to behave reliably best might be 
to make a Visualforce page and override the actions.

What exactly this button should do?

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete the standard button but you can edit it and override it with Visualforce page. You can find the all standard buttons for the opportunity are here. Setup-->App Setup --> Customize --> Opportunity --> Buttons and Links.

Form here you can either create any custom button or you can edit the standard button.

**Note : If you are overriding standard page with Visualforce page then make sure that the Visualforce page is having standardcontroller as selected object i.e. here in this case is "Opportunity"**

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom button to a standard page go to Setup -> Customize -> Opportunity -> Buttons & Links. Click "New" custom button and link button.

Here is a good tutorial for adding javascript actions.
http://www.interactiveties.com/b_execute_javascript_button.php

If you wanted to override standard buttons with visualforce pages, create your page first, then on the same buttons and link page from above, select "Edit" on the action you want to override.